# Just upgraded to 20.10 and Firefox is a resource hog now (kernel issue

Tags: kernel, firefox, 20.10

Just upgraded from 20.04 to 20.10 and suddenly Firefox is extremely slow and resource intensive. Especially JavaScript-heavy sites (that's 85% of all sites these days) loads slowly and can't be used as normal. *top* shows that 50%+ of the CPU is consumed by Firefox and Web content.

What's wrong? Some searching pointed to NVIDIA drivers as an issue, but I have Intel Graphics, so that's not it.

Any help appreciated.

Tried uninstalling extensions as suggested below, but while it helped a bit, the issue was back today. Firefox reports that "a script is causing issues" when things go slowly, <strike>so I guess it has something to do with Firefoxs javascript rendering.</strike>

Update: started Ubuntu with the old the kernel (5.4.0-52-generic) and now there's no issues. So this is a kernel issue, probably related to graphics.

Comment: Maybe some browser-history can cause the problem. So delete all brower-history. Another cause can be due to some outdated extensions. Check if all browser-extensions are up-to-date. If that doesn't help, close Firefox and delete the hidden folder .mozilla (this operation will remove all your preferences, extensions, themes, ...)

Comment: You can often learn some information by checking the browser's task manager. You can click through the GUI or you can just open `about:performance` in a new tab.

Comment: Do you have any details on said kernel issue? I'm having the exact same problem, but I can only choose between 5.8.0-26-generic and 5.8.0-25-generic. Using the latter didn't solve it.

Comment: Managed to install 5.4 kernel on 20.10. No idea how the OP had this even in their grub list, but it's obviously not a good idea. By just activating that kernel I'm stuck with no wifi drivers. Will have to do a reinstall with 20.04. Too bad Ubuntu doesn't have anything like Windows' system restore points :(

Comment: @depoulo, I upgraded from 20.04 with that kernel. Ubuntu usually keeps previous kernel versions when you upgrade.

Comment: if you start firefox with a new profile that will test for history,addons etc of your current profile